# Pointer to member function - doesn't want to work

Tags: c++, pointers

in this short code:

```
class X
{
private:
    class Y
    {

    public:
        typedef void (X::* ptr_to_mem)();
        Y(X* parent,ptr_to_mem ptr):parent_(parent),ptr_(ptr)
        {}
        void run()
        {
            parent_->*ptr_();//at this line I'm getting an error
        }
    private:
        X* parent_;
        ptr_to_mem ptr_;
    };

public:
    void some_fnc()
    {
        cout << "some_fnc";
    }

    void another()
    {
        Y y_(this,&X::some_fnc);
        y_.run();
    }

};
```

error:

```
error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((X::Y*)this)->X::Y::ptr_ (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((X::Y*)this)->X::Y::ptr_) (...)'
```

Comment: Why are you trying to maKe your code so complicated that it is hard to read? Oops - forgot - job security

Comment: #Ed Heal I'd have to have your mentality to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an extra pair of parens:

```
(parent_->*ptr_)();
```

See [C++FAQ lite 33.6](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.6).

Comment: hi Mat, I've deleted my last comment which was saying that I'm getting the same error. Of course your answer is correct and I will accept it. I placed those parenthesis in wrong place (parent_->*)ptr_(); . Thanks once again.

Comment: No problem - the syntax is just really hard to read _and_ write with those funky operators :)